# Easiest way to deploy an html page on a web server

Tags: html, sql, http, webserver

I have an html file that I use to extract a locally stored sqlite database file's informtaion, using some easy javascript.

Now I want to access this web page through http protocol (not file:/// scheme).

What configuration do you recommend to easily realize this manoeuvre ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: And if you have: Did you try under linux, windows, macos, do you want it on your local computer, do you want this html file be accessible via a domain?

Comment: I have tried to use Nginx web server under ubuntu to configure my own host on the computer. I need a setup to realize it the easiest way. I know the task is quite easy!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is lacking, but in general you want a webhost or setup your own computer for external connections.

I recommend finding a simple hosting site and learning the procedure from there.

Answer (score 0):

From the command line, navigate into your project folder, and run:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

You can then open `http://localhost:8000` in your browser, to view your page using the http:// protocol.

(I don't think this will work if your HTML file is actually PHP, which given that your description includes databases, it sounds like it might be. In that case, I would download something like MAMP.)

This answer assumes you're just trying to use the http:// protocol to test your page locally - like the other solution says, if you want to deploy your page so other people can see it, you'll need to find web hosting.